# Number of bits from entropy calculations

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

To calculate the entropy for a an event of a uniform distribution of this kind

- Events: "red" or "blue"
- Probabilities: P(red) = 0.5, P(blue) = 0.5

We just do $e = -\log_2(0.5)$

In this case it yields 1. Which I guess it means we need one bit.

If we have 4 values of 0.25, we need 2 bits. No surprises here.

However, lets say we have this non uniform distribution:

- Events: "red" or "blue"
- Probabilities: P(red) = 0.125, P(blue) = 0.875

Now, "red" should be represented with 3 bits, is this correct ? Why don't we still use just 1 bit?

Comment: Intuitively, the harder to predict an event, the bigger its entropy. No wonder that low-probability events have bigger entropy.

Comment: But the question is: why do we represent it with 3 bits in this case ? @kludg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "red" should be represented with 3 bits, is this correct ?

No. You could say that "red" gives 3 bits of information; and you could also say that the "ideal" code should assign 3 bits to "red" and 0.19 bits to blue - so that in average you use 0.54 bits, which is the entropy.  But of course, you can't do that. The optimal code is still 1 bit for each symbol.

To attain the entropy (and use few bits for blue -or blueish- symbols) you need to code the extensions of the source. See eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835649/compressing-binary-numbers/836319).

Comment: Is there any example you can give where the bit reduction like using 3 and 1 is possible?

Comment: No, of course not. You can't beat the optimal trivial code  (1 bit for each symbol).
You need to understand the concept of coding the enxtension of the source. Only in that case (when you code the n-th extension of the source, for some big n), you should find that a macro symbol is coded with approximately 3 bits for each red element plus 0.19 bits for each blue element.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am terrible at this. I was just curious about the basic idea.

Comment: I understand though that the average entropy is less than the one for a uniform distribution, that would be 1 still